# Error Code: 1064 doesnt allow to run the query

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

i tried to run the following query but when ever i try to do it, it gives the following error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET @tab = CONCAT("monitorTable_",ir);

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `Modification`$$
BEGIN
    SET @tab = CONCAT("monitorTable_",pr);
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS uniques;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE uniques (`id` INT, `timestamp` DATETIME);
    SET @sqlstring = CONCAT("INSERT INTO uniques SELECT id,timestamp FROM ",@tab," GROUP BY id");
    PREPARE stmt FROM @sqlstring;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS uniquescount;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE uniquescount (`cnt` INT, `dat` DATETIME);
    INSERT INTO uniquescount SELECT COUNT(id) AS cnt ,DATE(TIMESTAMP) AS dat FROM uniques GROUP BY DATE(TIMESTAMP);
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS nonuniquescount;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE nonuniquescount (`cnt` INT, `dat` DATETIME);
    SET @sqlstring = CONCAT("INSERT INTO nonuniquescount SELECT COUNT(id) AS cnt ,DATE(TIMESTAMP) AS dat 
FROM ",@tab," GROUP BY DATE(TIMESTAMP)");
    PREPARE stmt FROM @sqlstring;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    SELECT un.cnt AS ucnt, nu.cnt AS cnt, nu.dat AS dat FROM uniquescount un RIGHT JOIN nonuniquescount nu ON un.dat = nu.dat;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that `BEGIN - END` block can't exist independently.
`Create procedure` statement is missing in your code after which the `BEGIN - END` block should be included.

```
delimiter $$

CREATE PROCEDURE Modification()
BEGIN
-- your code block here
END;

$$

delimiter ;
```